# Retrieve value from database for the particular id which is in url using class based views in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-class-based-views

I need to display value into textbox fields in template page which is get from the database for the particular id. After that i need to edit those details which is needed and to update those values into database.These things are done by function based views easily. But now i want to do that it in class based views.Which view is used to do that. Can anyone help me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) for this task.

**UPDATE**: If you want to display instance details on one page and the edit form on another then use the [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) for the first step.

Comment: yes i used UpdateView. But how to get those values from database and display into template page.

Comment: The `UpdateView` will do it automatically.  You only need to set up the url with a `pk` regex to this view and create the template with the form.